# Regular expression based searching for Mercurial changeset

Tags: regex, mercurial

I would like to be able to perform regular expression-type searches on Mercurial changesets and display results using `log`.

I've come up with the following function, which seems to work, but has a number of possible bugs (e.g. `$1` is in line of text containing the word `changeset`).

```
function hgs { hg log `hg log | grep changeset | grep "$1" \
    | sed 's/changeset: *//g' | sed 's/:.*$//g' | \
    awk '{print " -r " $0}'`; }

export -f hgs
```

Am I trying to recreate something here that already exists as a well-tested solution elsewhere?

Comment: `hg log -k <keyword>` won't give you regex, but you can search by keyword. Also, you can simplify your function by first calling `hg log --template "<template>"` to create something that's easier to parse. For instance, you could do `hg log --template "{rev}:{sub('\n','',desc)}\n"` to get local revision number and changeset description (with newlines stripped out). I'm not entirely clear about what you want to search with a regex, but I expect the description is more useful than the `changeset: rev:node` line which is what your function seem to rely on.

Answer (score 1):

It pretty much looks like a combination of using `hg grep`, making use revsets and templated output could possibly help you (check `hg help revsets`, `hg help templates`, `hg help grep` and possibly also `hg help fileset`).

E.g. to find all changes to config.lib or where the commit message contains 'pkgconfig' which were made after 2010:

`hg log -r"(file('config.lib') or desc('pkgconfig')) and date('>2010')"`

revsets are very powerful. You can also sort, limit to a certain number of changesets, combine different requirements...

Using the `--template` argument to `hg log` can be used to format the output in any pattern you desire.